# Error when installing grunt-browser-sync with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, npm, browser-sync

I'm trying to install the **grunt-browser-sync** plugin via **npm** (version 3.3.8):

```
npm install grunt-browser-sync --save-dev
```

First my terminal hangs at loading xmlhttprequest:
[image]

Then after waiting a while, I get this error:
[image]

If I navigate in my browser to the url https://github.com/rase-/node-XMLHttpRequest/archive/a6b6f2.tar.gz, it works..

I'm working on Windows 7 Enterprise. 
npm version 3.3.8. 
I'm working behind a proxy, but the settings are correct, because **I can install other npm modules**.

What I already tried:

- use different version of npm (3.3.1, 3.3.5, 3.3.6, 3.3.7)
- npm cache clean

Comment: If you can get to the package maybe you can try to download the package from the source and then install it manually: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: It didn't work.. I downloaded the grunt-browser-sync package on github and tried to install it, but I get the same error as above.

Comment: I can't help you any further besides telling you to double-check your npm proxy configuration, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that npm is not that great with HTTPS over a proxy. Changing the registry URL from HTTPS to HTTP is a work around:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

But your problem doesn't seems to end here as it's not getting the dependency from http://registry.npmjs.org,
but from: https://github.com/rase-/node-XMLHttpRequest/archive/a6b6f2.tar.gz

Since you're behind a proxy, using npm can be a real pain sometimes. So you've to configure `npm` to work with your web proxy. Here is an example:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Comment: I know how to set my proxy and registry. I already did that. See my config: http://snag.gy/y6rwY.jpg I can download other npm modules. The problem is specific to grunt-browser-sync